# The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the map value type

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract-class

I'm trying to create a way to sort some items that I have.

```
abstract class IComposableOrderBy {
  String sortBy();
}

class SortByCreatedAt implements IComposableOrderBy {
  @override
  String sortBy() => r'{ order_by: {created_at: $sort} }';
}

class SortByEmptyFirst implements IComposableOrderBy {
  @override
  String sortBy() => r'{ products_aggregate: {count: desc} }';
}

enum OrderBy {
  asc,
  desc,
}

enum SortOptions {
  byCreatedAt,
  byEmptyFolder,
}
```

The problem is... When I tried to use it as a Map, I received this error The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the map value type 'IComposableOrderBy'.

```
final Map<SortOptions, IComposableOrderBy> _sortOptions = {
    SortOptions.byCreatedAt: SortByCreatedAt,
    SortOptions.byEmptyFolder: SortByEmptyFirst
  };
```

does Dart not have support for this?

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare `Map<SortOptions, IComposableOrderBy>`, you must pass instance of `IComposableOrderBy` class, not its class `Type`, change it to:

```
final Map<SortOptions, IComposableOrderBy> _sortOptions = {
    SortOptions.byCreatedAt: SortByCreatedAt(),
    SortOptions.byEmptyFolder: SortByEmptyFirst()
  };
```